# Handle Event Remote Control

Tags: android, events, bluetooth

I'm trying to to write a program, to use my Android Phone as Bluetooth Remote Control.
My problem:

When I push a button, and hold em down `ACTION_DOWN`, the program should send every 30ms a defined signal, for example: `sendData(Integer.toString(1));`, while the button is down.

How can I realize this?!

Answer (score 0):

You basically start a thread on `ACTION_DOWN` and terminate it on the `ACTION_UP` event.

Inside of that thread you do your work every 30 milliseconds if you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your eventhandler, you can use a class extended from Handler to execute a function after a certain amount of time with the `sendMessageDelayed` method. Within the method called through `sendMessageDelayed`, you can once again call the same method, causing it to repeat.

To make the loop stop, call `removeMessages` in the handler class.

Comment: Why would he need a BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I had misread his question and assumed he also wanted to use Bluetooth to control the actions. I shall update my answer.